# How do I create an event listener on a property in every instance of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 objects (ie instances of a class), and I need to set an event listener on the "im" property, that runs the function "squash()".

I attempted to use `this.im.click(squash())` in the class, but that did not work.  How can I create the event listener?

```
let divs = $(".flies");
divs.each(function(i){
  let img = $("<img/>");
  img.attr({
    "id": i,
    "src": "http://clipart-library.com/images/8iznoLG8T.png"});
  $(this).append(img)
});

class Fly {
  constructor(div, im, alive){
    this.div = div;
    this.im = im;
    this.alive = true;
  }
  squash(){
    this.alive= false;
    this.element.css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
  }

let fly1 = new Fly($('#fly1'), $('#0'), true);
let fly2 = new Fly($('#fly2'), $('#1'), true);
let fly3 = new Fly($('#fly3'), $('#2'), true);
let fly4 = new Fly($('#fly4'), $('#3'), true);
let fly5 = new Fly($('#fly5'), $('#4'), true);
```

Comment: `this.im.click(squash)` (no brackets) your invoking the function not adding a click handler with `this.im.click(squash())`

Comment: @Liam that changes context of `this`

Comment: Well that's a different issue. If `squash` is a click handler then `this` isn't what the OP thinks it is anyway.

Comment: @Liam Thanks so much!  Where should I put it?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for responding! Where do you recommend I place ```this.im.click(squash)```?

Answer (score 0):

Use `im.click(this.squash.bind(this));`

```js
class Fly {
  constructor(div, im, alive){
    this.div = div;
    this.im = im;
    this.alive = true;
    this.init()
  }

  init(){
    this.im.click(this.squash.bind(this));
  } 
  
  squash(){
    this.alive= false;
    // wasn't sure what `element` is supposed to be, used `div` instead
    this.div.css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
  }

let fly1 = new Fly($('#fly1'), $('#0'), true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="0">Click to hide content</button>

<div id="fly1">Content 1</div>
```